# Query Current State for Possible Future States in State Machine

Tags: xaml, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, state-machine

I'm looking for a way to query a state in a state machine to find out what the possible destinations are for that state. I know that one option is to parse the Xaml for the information that I need. Is there another way? Possibly by querying the state object in .NET code?

The goal is to decrease the number of places that the business logic for the state transitions is stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced this question too today - I thought mperrenoud03's code would solve it, but alas it didn't work for me under .NET 4.5 RC. The reason is that it reflected an internal/private type *System.Activities.Statements.InternalState* rather than *System.Activities.Statements.State*.

The InternalState object had a Transitions collection, which I could probably obtain by further reflection ... but I felt this took me way past the smell test.

A solution I found which is working so far is this NuGet: http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Activities.Extensions. It has a WF Extension called *StateMachineStateTracker*. At any time, you can ask it for the current StateMachine, and its collection of Transitions.

Comment: nice addition here - that's a lot easer than reflecting it :D

Comment: Small comment about the author - Ron Jacobs had contribute to the WF community by writing passionate and excellent blog posts, tutorials and videos over the years. Unfortunately at the age of 48 he was diagnosed with the very rare and very painful Dercums Disease. You can find Ron's WF blog here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rjacobs/ and personal site here: https://ronljacobs.wordpress.com/. Ron - We all wish you all the best and hope you'll get back to us soon

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.  If you issue the following statement you can get the state machine itself from a custom activity.

```
this.GetType().GetProperty("Parent",
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(this, null)
```

Then on the state machine object is a property named Transitions -- each Transition has a To property incidating what State they transition to.

Incidentally you can also grab the Trigger and Condition from that object! :)

I hope this helps!